# Couldn't find a `pages` directory. nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I do everything according to the instructions https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started/setup

I run `npm run dev`

And displays an error

```
Div-Man@DivMan MINGW64 /f/nextjs/hello-next
$ npm run dev

> hello-next@1.0.0 dev F:\nextjs\hello-next
> next

> Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-next@1.0.0 dev: `next`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-next@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Div-Man\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-08T07_58_57_773Z-debug.log
```

---

```
 $ node -v
 v10.6.0

 $ npm -v
 6.1.0
```

windows 8.1

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.1"
  }
}
```

---

```
   npm start

> hello-next@1.0.0 start F:\nextjs\hello-next
> next start

Error: Could not find a valid build in the 'F:\nextjs\hello-next\.next' director                 y! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
    at Server.readBuildId (F:\nextjs\hello-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\ne                 xt-server.js:753:15)
    at new Server (F:\nextjs\hello-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-serve                 r.js:80:25)
    at module.exports (F:\nextjs\hello-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.j                 s:6:10)
    at _callee$ (F:\nextjs\hello-next\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-se                 rver.js:33:37)
    at tryCatch (F:\nextjs\hello-next\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.j                 s:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (F:\nextjs\hello-next\node_modules\regenera                 tor-runtime\runtime.js:288:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (F:\nextjs\hello-next\                 node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:114:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (F:\nextjs\hello-next\node_modules\@babel\runtime-core                 js2\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:5:24)
    at _next (F:\nextjs\hello-next\node_modules\@babel\runtime-corejs2\helpers\a                 syncToGenerator.js:27:9)
    at F:\nextjs\hello-next\node_modules\@babel\runtime-corejs2\helpers\asyncToG                 enerator.js:34:7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-next@1.0.0 start: `next start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-next@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                 ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Div-Man\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-08T08_25_2                 3_194Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 6):

The nextJS need to "pages" directory.

Make the "pages" and then inside make the index.js. (ex.pages/index.js)

Comment: Thanks, why it is not written in the instructions?

Comment: Awwww haha I didn't know that. but when I read the NextJS document, there already explain. but it's not easy catch a once. 
So, When I first time to study nextjs, I watch the lecture in youtube.